# How do I do Short URLs in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes, short-url

Suppose I want to publish (like in paper catalogs) some "short URLs" that are easy to type/remember, but I want them to redirect to a verbose, SEO-friendly URL.  How do I accomplish that with MVC routes?

Example:

> http://mysite.com/disney

becomes

> http://mysite.com/travel/planning-your-disney-vacation (with "travel" as the Controller)

The things I've tried:

1. Just setup a route for it. **Problem:** the URL doesn't change in the browser (it stays "/disney".
2. Use NuGet package RouteMagic (see [Haacked's article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/02/redirecting-routes-to-maintain-persistent-urls.aspx)).  **Problem:** I get an error: The RouteData must contain an item named 'controller' with a non-empty string value.  I think this is because I don't have a static word before my controller ("travel") like he did (with "foo" and "bar")???
3. Use a redirect module (like [Ian Mercer's](http://blog.abodit.com/2010/04/a-simple-redirect-route-handler-for-asp-net-3-5-routing/)). **Problem:** the route matches on my HTML.ActionLinks when creating URLs which I don't want (Haacked mentions this in his article and says that's why he has GetVirtualPath return NULL ...?)

I'm out of ideas, so any would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set up a catch-all type route, to direct all /something requests to a specific action and controller, something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ShortUrls",
    "{name}",
    new {controller = "ShortUrl", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

(depending on how the rest of your routing is set up, you probably don't want to do it exactly like this as it will likely cause you some serious routing headaches - but this works here for the sake of simplicity)

Then just have your action redirect to the desired URL, based on the specified value:

```
public class ShortUrlController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /ShortUrl/

    public ActionResult Index(string name)
    {
        var urls = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        urls.Add("disney", "http://mysite.com/travel/planning-your-disney-vacation");
        urls.Add("scuba", "http://mysite.com/travel/planning-your-scuba-vacation");

        return Redirect(urls[name]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I already have a "catchall" route, so this won't work (...unfortunately).

Comment: If you added a Route Constraint to the ShortUrls catchall to only match a specified list of strings, would that work for you?

Comment: Kristian, THAT WORKED! After re-reading your Post - to actually understand what you were proposing! - and days of researching Route Constraints, and then coming up with the Regular Expression that would work, AND THEN fixing my typos (can you believe - 3 of them in that little bit of code!?!??), I finally got it to work! ... I could hardly believe it!  **THANK YOU!!!!!**

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem. 
In my Global:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ShortUrls",
    "{name}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In my Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
    return View(name);
}
```

This way is dynamic, didn't want to have to recompile every time I needed to add a new page.

Answer (score 0):

To shorten a URL you should use URL rewriting technique.

Some tutorials on subject:

- [url-rewriting-with-urlrewriternet](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.in/2008/07/url-rewriting-with-urlrewriternet.html)
- [url-routing-with-asp-net-4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)
- [URL rewriting in .Net](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx)

Comment: The 4Guys article is non-MVC, as is - I suspect - the first one since it's written in 2008.  The 2nd one is the only "relevent" one and doesn't tell me anything helpful.